# Customize doxygen formatting of pure virtual function

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

Let's say I have a C++ class with a pure virtual function like this:

```
class Thing {
public:
    virtual void doStuff(int a, int b) = 0;
}
```

When doxygen runs over this, you get a line in the (HTML) docs that looks like:

> virtual void doStuff(int a, int b)=0

The thing is, this is technically correct but I think it looks really ugly to have that '=0' at the end there. The fact that this function is pure virtual (or even that it is virtual) does not matter to my customers.

So is there any way to tell doxygen to hack off that '=0'? Or more generally to customize this output?

Comment: What version of Doxygen are you using? At least with 1.8.11 I couldn't reproduce this. Such pure virtual functions are actually displayed with a 'tag' "_pure virtual_" to the very right of the function signature.